# Auto refreshing browser slows over time

Tags: excel, vba, performance, lag

I have an Excel VBA program that uses an open IE window with a web page that automatically refreshes every 120 seconds.  At the beginning of a fresh reboot/cycle, the web page has data that takes about 10 seconds to completely load, as soon as it's complete, the VBA program grabs the data.

Over time, the time it takes for the data to completely show on the browser takes longer and longer.  Eventually after running for 36-48 hours, the browser takes longer than 120 seconds to complete, leaving my program dead in the wind.  The only way to get it back working properly is a complete shutdown of the computer.

Is the computer just running out of memory over time? I shut off caching, that didn't appear to change anything.  What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you delete your IE object and create a new one?

Comment: Does not work.  I tried shutting down Excel and IE and reopening.  Does not change anything, the IE is still sluggish.  Only thing that works is a complete reboot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296186/ie-in-vba-code-lose-connection/50297406#50297406 take a look at answer here and see if it helps

Comment: Can you reopen the IE windows every n requests? May be that workarounds the resources leak.